# Tkinter .bind() method

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

Im trying to make a tic-tac-toe game, but every time i run the program, the function is automatically executing for some reason. code so far below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

x_turn = True

def button_clicked(b):
    global x_turn
    print('Executed')
        if x_turn is True:
            b.config(text='X')
            x_turn = False
        else:
            b.config(text='O')
            x_turn = True

button1 = Button(root, text='', width=6, height=2)
button1.bind('<Button1>', button_clicked(button1))
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

button2 = Button(root, text='', width=6, height=2)
button2.bind('<Button1>', button_clicked(button2))
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)

button3 = Button(root, text='', width=6, height=2)
button3.bind('<Button1>', button_clicked(button3))
button3.grid(row=0, column=2)

button4 = Button(root, text='', width=6, height=2)
button4.bind('<Button1>', button_clicked(button4))
button4.grid(row=1, column=0)

button5 = Button(root, text='', width=6, height=2)
button5.bind('<Button1>', button_clicked(button5))
button5.grid(row=1, column=1)

button6 = Button(root, text='', width=6, height=2)
button6.bind('<Button1>', button_clicked(button6))
button6.grid(row=1, column=2)

button7 = Button(root, text='', width=6, height=2)
button7.bind('<Button1>', button_clicked(button7))
button7.grid(row=2, column=0)

button8 = Button(root, text='', width=6, height=2)
button8.bind('<Button1>', button_clicked(button8))
button8.grid(row=2, column=1)

button9 = Button(root, text='', width=6, height=2)
button9.bind('<Button1>', button_clicked(button9))
button9.grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

When i run the program it automatically calls the function 9 times and i cant figure out why. is there some wierd rule i dont know about?

Answer (score 1):

It automatically calls `button_clicked` 9 times, because you told it to call it 9 times with your 9 `buttonX.bind...` calls.

The [bind method](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html#bind) takes a function as a parameter.  You're not passing in a function, you're passing in the return value from `button_clicked(b)`.

[`button_clicked` is a function, but `button_clicked(some_parameter)` means calling that function, and using the return value as the parameter]

There are a few ways to pass in a function that takes parameters to the bind method.  One way is to pass in an anonymous [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) that will call your `real` function when it is called.

So, instead of this:

```
button1.bind('<Button1>', button_clicked(button1))
```

change all your calls to look something like this:

```
button1.bind('<Button1>', lambda: button_clicked(button1))
```

Comment: I get an error when i use lambda.

Comment: @jjguidry: maybe try: `button1.bind('<Button1>', command=lambda: button_clicked(button1))`.

Comment: Nope :(    
"bind() got an unexpected keyword argument 'command'"

Comment: Hmm, I just went by the dup question to yours.  The docs I liinked seem to suggest the parameter is called `func`.  Try `button1.bind('<Button1>', func=lambda: button_clicked(button1))`.  If this doesn't work, you may have to ask a new question.

Comment: yeah that didnt work either :( thanks for your help though